# How to limit .appearance to NOT effect system ViewControllers like UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I use `appearance` in an existing app for styling and to apply different themes. For example I used `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(...)` to apply a custom font and white color to all `UIBarButtonItem`s within my app.

Now I noticed that in `UIActivityViewController` the save and cancel buttons are missing. They are not really missing but hidden as being shown as white text on a white background. This is not intended of course.

Is there any easy way to NOT apply appearances to such system Views/ViewConrollers but only to the View/ViewControllers of my own app? Something like `...appearance(whenNOTContainedIn...)`

Using `...appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf...)` would be quite cumbersome since I use `UIBarButtonItems` in many differnt containers without a common super class.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but you can always create a subclass of UIBarButtonItem and use that instead on your view controllers. For example:

```
class AppBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        tintColor = .green
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        tintColor = .green
    }
}
```